# Deadlock situation in threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

want to know what is deadlock condition in threads, because in many of the books i studied how to avoid deadlock situation, i just want to know what is deadlock situation and a example code for that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Deadlock is a situation that a concurrent program cannot proceed.

> A thread is waiting for another
>   thread, while the other thread is
>   waiting for the first thread's
>   completion.

The commonly used real world example is a traffic flow.

[image]

No traffic can move until the other queue moves.

You may find a good discussion on deadlocks [here](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/fall04/os/c10/index.html).

Update : This is one java [example](http://examples.oreilly.com/9781565923713/Deadlock.java) I found on web (Oreilly book). It has comments on that so you can understand it easily.

[Dining Philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) is another good example to understand the deadlocks.

*removed dead Imageshack link*

Dead lock detection and Deadlock prevention are two of related areas that might be useful while learning about the deadlocks.

Comment: I like this diagram.  This is essentially what my professor showed me when I was learning concurrency and it has served me well.

Comment: it is worth noting that it is more important to prevent a deadlock than to figure out deadlock-breaking mechanisms. In most cases, the former is much easier to implement. Unless you are just killing deadlocked threads :)

Comment: +1 for the excellent diagram. Where did you get it ? Perfect example of how a picture is worth a 1000 words.

Answer (score 6):

Deadlock is when A waits on B and B waits on A.

So you could have in thread A:

```
while(B.incomplete()){
    B.wait();
} A.complete = true;
```

and have in thread B:

```
while(A.incomplete()){
    A.wait();
} B.complete = true;
```

Comment: I realize this is a pretty trivial example, but you get the idea, right?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a deadlock that doesn't use `wait`. As long as you've got synchronization, there's a potential for deadlock.

```
public class Deadlock {
  static class Deadlocker {
    private Deadlocker other;

    public void setOther(Deadlocker other) {
      this.other = other;
    }

    synchronized void doSomethingWithOther() {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
      other.doSomething();
    }

    synchronized void doSomething() {
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Deadlocker d1 = new Deadlocker();
    final Deadlocker d2 = new Deadlocker();
    d1.setOther(d2);
    d2.setOther(d1);

    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        d1.doSomethingWithOther();
      }
    };

    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        d2.doSomethingWithOther();
      }
    };

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}
```

The deadlock occurs when `t1` is in `d1.doSomethingWithOther()` (and hence has a lock on `d1`) and `t2` is in `d2.doSomethingWithOther()` (and hence has a lock on `d2`). When each thread tries to call `doSomething()` on the object the *other* thread has a lock on, they end up stuck, waiting for each other.

Note that a deadlock doesn't necessarily involve only two threads. It's possible to have a cycle of any size. Worse, once a deadlock has occurred, any other thread that attempts to obtain a lock that a deadlocked thread is already holding will end up becoming effectively deadlocked itself, even without being in the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock is caused by resource contention that is not directly solvable without some sort of resource control (such as a graph cycle which relies on two resource locks).

One of the most common (and generally used for illustration) deadlock scenarios is lock inversion:

- Consider an application which has two critical resources (resA, resB), and two locks (lockA, lockB). Each resource is protected by the corresponding lock (resA => lockA, resB => lockB).
- Two resources are contending for the resources, Thread A reserves lockA (and thus resource A) and then is suspended for a context switch) before being able to reserve lockB. Thread B receives control, reserves lockB and then attempts to reserve lockA. This causes the thread to be suspended and control returned back to Thread A, who is waiting on lockB, which is held be Thread B.

In this scenario you will have a deadlock because of a cyclic dependency between the two threads on the two contended resources (lockA and lockB) which cannot be resolved without separate intervention.

This can be trivially resolved by either:

1. Ensuring the two locks are resolved in order (not the best choice)
2. Only holding one lock for each critical section at a time (i.e. release lockA before attempting to acquire lockB)

Comment: +1 And resources must be mutually exclusive otherwise they are not locked.

Comment: Resolution 1 is actually better.  Let's assume that the locks are for distinct data structures.  If you hold only one lock at a time, then you don't simultaneously have exclusive access to both data structures, and certain operations cannot be safely performed.  OTOH, if you replace the two locks with one, you reduce the scope for concurrency; e.g. for other operations that required only one of the two original locks.

Comment: Actually I wasnt saying to replace the two locks with one lock, but just to work to optimally only own one lock at a time. There are times where you must own both locks, and in this case #1 is obviously the preferred design.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the following threads of logic.

1. In catch-22, the novel,
   the fighter pilot was to be grounded due to insanity. He could prove against the case of insanity by saying he was not insane so that he could fly again. But by asking, wanting to fly into battle to endanger his life would demonstrate that he is crazy.
2. North Korea wants the G7 to deliver economic aid before stopping uranium refinement. The US and Japan says "No Way, because they would renege after getting the aid."
3. System reboot conflict.

   1. The system would not shut down until
      all user processes have been
      terminated.
   2. The editor, a user process would not
      terminate unless the edit has been
      saved.
   3. The edit cannot be saved unless the
      usb drive is present because the
      editor executable was called from
      the usb drive.
   4. The usb drive was dismounted because
      of a driver upgrade. The usb drive
      could not be mounted until the
      system is shut down and rebooted.
4. The Android robot has prime directives

   A robot may not injure a human being or, through inaction, allow a human being to come to harm.

   A robot must obey any orders given to it by human beings, except where such orders would conflict with the First directive.

   A robot must protect its own existence as long as such protection does not conflict with the First or Second directive.

The human occupants of the base sent robot to retrieve a radio-active power source. Without the power source, the base would shut down and the human colony would die. But the robot discovers that the power source is so powerful and unshielded, handling it would cause the robot to malfunction and become a danger to the human colony.

Comment: 'You've got flies in your eyes,' Yossarian repeated. 'That's probably why you can't see them.'

Comment: We've got files in our system that we probably can't see because there are deadlocks?

Answer (score 1):

```
DeadLock is a situation when first thread is waiting for second Thread, 

while  Second Thread is waiting for first thread's completion.
```

**See this Traffic Deadlock to better UnderStand DeadLock situation**

[image]

[image]

```
**Java Code Demo**

public class DeadLockDemo 
{
   public static Object object1 = new Object();
   public static Object object2 = new Object();
   private int index;
   public static void main(String[] a) {
      Thread t1 = new Thread1();
      Thread t2 = new Thread2();
      t1.start();
      t2.start();
   }
   private static class Thread1 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (object1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1...");
            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...");
            synchronized (object2) {
               System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   }
   private static class Thread2 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (object2) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 2...");
            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Waiting for lock 1...");
            synchronized (object1) {
               System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 2 & 1...");
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock is when two (or more) threads are each waiting for the other to finish. Thread A cannot complete until thread B does something, and thread B cannot finish until thread A does something else.

Answer (score 0):

> Threads deadlock when waiting on each
>   other to release some resources, but
>   by performing that blocking wait,
>   they're not releasing the resources
>   the other threads need in order to
>   unblock. The threads can't make any
>   progress until the resources are
>   released, but because they're not
>   making progress, the resources will
>   never be released, the threads are
>   locked up, and thus "deadlock."

A [nice article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163352.aspx) by Stephen Toub might help you a bit.